# Swift + Firebase Preload data in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am implementing a tableview which pulls data from Firebase. My tableview is divided into sections which are dynamically dependent on the entries in Firebase and retrieving data in viewdidload would crash the app.

How do I pull data from Firebase in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions prior to viewdidload? This tableview is my first view controller.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    FIRApp.configure()
    return true
}
```

//In tableview controller

```
class MyTableViewController: UITableViewController {

var ref: FIRDatabaseReference!
private var _refHandle: FIRDatabaseHandle!
var mileageDatabase: [FIRDataSnapshot]! = []
var dates: [(String)] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print("View did load \(self.dates)")
    configureDatabase()

    self.tableView = UITableView(frame: self.tableView.frame, style: .Grouped)

}



func configureDatabase() {
    ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

    _refHandle = self.ref.child("mileage").observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
        self.mileageDatabase.append(snapshot)
        self.tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forRow: self.mileageDatabase.count - 1, inSection: 0)].reverse(), withRowAnimation: .Automatic)


    })

self.ref.child("mileage").queryOrderedByChild("date").observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
       print(snapshot.value?["date"])
       self.dates.append(snapshot.value?["date"] as! String)            
       // Here I will do some magic to sort out unique dates
    })

}

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

      return self.dates.count
}
```

Comment: Can you paste the way you load your data here ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok , you can go for global variables. Instead of declaring the variable "dates" inside your `MyTableViewController` you can declare it as global variable.

`public var dates: [(String)] = []`.

The code should be outside of any class's scope

Now move following code to `func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool`

```
ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

ref.child("mileage").queryOrderedByChild("date").observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
       print(snapshot.value?["date"])
      dates.append(snapshot.value?["date"] as! String)            
       // Here I will do some magic to sort out unique dates
    })
```

You will have your data at the time of `viewDidLoad`

Comment: @rejithr It doesn't work though. I placed the code above at didFinishLaunchingWithOptions and declared dates as a global variable but Firebase still calls the code after viewDidLoad.

Comment: Ok , Ideally it should not. Your callback may be getting delayed. If this does not solve the problem , then call tableview.reload() after you get the data. You can either show blank screen or activity indicator. Just now i tried same with my code , i am getting response before viewdidLoad